# How Jackson handles mapping conflict?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson2

I have the following class with a property "key" that maps to 2 different `JSON` fields

```
public class A {

    @JsonAlias("Key")
    private String key;

    @JsonProperty("NewKey")
    private void unpackNewKey(Map<String, String> NewKey) {
        key = NewKey.get("value");
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON to deserialize.

```
{
    "NewKey": {
        "value": "newkey",
    },
    "Key": "key"
}
```

If I deserialize the above json to A.class

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
A a = mapper.readValue(json, A.class)
```

What would be the value of the `a.key`? will it be `newkey` or `key`? Trying to understand how jackson handles conflict. Can I specify the order? for example, if I want the `key` to always map to `NewKey` if both `Key` and `NewKey` exist in the json, what should I do?

Comment: have you tried ? do you get any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, where you use `@JsonAlias("Key")` and `@JsonProperty("NewKey")` order depends from an order of `key-value` pairs in `JSON` payload. If you want to always deserialise with `NewKey` key precedence, you need to implement this in custom `JSON Deserialiser` or in constructor. Simple example you can find below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{}", A.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"Key\": \"key\"}", A.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"NewKey\": {\"value\": \"newkey\"}}", A.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"Key\": \"key\", \"NewKey\": {\"value\": \"newkey\"}}", A.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"NewKey\": {\"value\": \"newkey\"}, \"Key\": \"key\"}", A.class));
    }
}

class A {

    private String key;

    @JsonCreator
    public A(Map<String, Object> json) {
        final String key = Objects.toString(json.get("Key"), null);
        final Map newKey = (Map) json.getOrDefault("NewKey", Collections.emptyMap());
        this.key = Objects.toString(newKey.get("value"), key);
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
null
key
newkey
newkey
newkey
```